# 3 JavaScript files talking to each other

Tags: javascript

How can 3 separate JavaScript files "talk to each other" outside of a browser? Can someone expound on how these 3 different JS files can use each other's code? How to avoid circular dependencies, etc?

foo.js
bar.js
mud.js

I know there are things like "var foo = require(./foo.js)" and "module.exports" but right now it's not making much sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of a browser?" Do you mean another environment like Node?

Comment: yes, something like Node is what I mean

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript outside of the browser by using Node.js http://nodejs.org/

You can have a 'parent' or 'top level' javascript file execute 'WebWorkers'. A parent js file can communicate back and forth to a WebWorker. To have web workers talk to each other, they will have to communicate through the parent javascript file https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 1):

When using node.js as your JS environment, working with multiple files works like this:

File 1, a person class:

```
// person.js
var Person = function(name) { this.name = name; }
Person.prototype.greet = function() { console.log("Hello, "+ this.name) }
module.exports = Person;
```

File 2, a dog:

```
// dog.js
var Dog = function(name) { this.name = name; }
Person.prototype.woof = function() { console.log(this.name + " barks") }
module.exports = Dog;
```

File 3, a program that requires the Person class

```
// greet_sue.js
var Person = require('./person.js');
var Dog = require('./dog');

var sue = new Person("Sue");
sue.greet(); // Hello, Sue

var dog - new Dog("Fido");
dog.woof(); // Fido barks
```

Run program at command line with:

```
$ node greet_sue.js
Hello, Sue
Fido barks
```

---

> How can 3 separate JavaScript files "talk to each other" outside of a browser?

Use node.js

> Can someone expound on how these 3 different JS files can use each other's code?

Some files assign objects and values to `module.exports`, which can be imported in other files when that file is `require()`'d.

> How to avoid circular dependencies, etc?

Good program structure. If you've designed your program well, this shouldn't be a concern. In my example, `Person` should not have to care about how it's greeting is used. It simple provides a way to greet a person. The `greet_sue.js` file is responsible for managing the greeting.

That said, dependency management is hard, and is a complex problem not unique to node.js.

Comment: thanks, what if you want to use multiple modules? is that possible?

Comment: if so, can you show what that might be like with a 3rd JS file?

Comment: @AlexMills You would include a third JS file just like the second. Any file can require the exports of as many other files as you want.